# can I Expose Pod Information to Containers Through Environment Variables with deployments?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm using kubernetes and changed all my replication controllers to deployments (the new RC from k8s ).

I used to  Expose Pod Information of Containers Through Environment Variables as described in here:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/

So I used it like that:

```
  - name: MY_POD_NAME
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        fieldPath: metadata.name
```

and it was working, after changing to deployments looks like that metadata.name is not defined and I can not use this as an Environment Variables anymore.

Does anyone know if this functionality is still working on deployments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This deploymned works for me. can you test this in your cluster?

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    k8s-app: nginx
    tier: network-tools
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: nginx
    spec:      
      containers:
      - name: nginx       
        image: nginx        
        env: 
        - name: SSHD
          value: TURE
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace       
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name        
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Comment: So it was something to do with helm, and not related to the deployment itself.    https://helm.sh/

Comment: helm won't change anything in the deployment file format. is there a easy way to re-create your issue. I can try it on my cluster.